# Selecting a random month (Generating a random integer between a set range)

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a random integer between 1 and 12 to serve as the month selection.
Code:

```
def randomMonthNumber(size=2, chars=string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(size))


monthnumber = randomMonthNumber()
If monthnumber > 12
    monthnumber

print(monthnumber)
```

At the moment I've tried to code it so that if the random number selected in the function is greater than 12 it runs the function again (and will keep doing so until the integer is below 12) and stores it in `monthnumber` but I keep getting syntax error at the If statement.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the i to lowercase in If

Answer (score 3):

Instead of generating random string of size and checking if it is greater than 12, generate a random number between 1 and 12.

```
def randomMonthNumber():
    return random.randint(1,12)
```

Above code will return a number between 1 and 12 (both inclusive).
Or if if you want to do it in your method, divide the number by 12 and then 1 to it get it between 1 and 12.

```
if monthnumber > 12:
    monthnumber = 1 + monthnumber%12
```

Comment: Please be aware that Python's `random.randint` **includes** both end points, therefore it should be `(1,12)` and not `(1,13)`

Comment: These solutions worked great thanks! Gotta wait 10 mins before accepting as soln.

Comment: Is there anyway to 'tip the scales' and make the random generator more likely to select a number above say 7 for example?

Comment: random.randint(8,12)

Comment: @mya  something along the lines of  `random.choices(range(1,13), weights=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2], k=1)`  - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: @PatrickArtner But it would still generate numbers from 1 to 6. `weights` parameter  is just adjusting the probabilites in the list.

Comment: @SAI :: _Is there anyway to 'tip the scales' and make the random generator more likely to select a number above say 7 for example? – mya205 1_  ... so what? that is **exactly** what was asked in the comment....